# Setting options of object after defining it

Tags: graphics, options, assignment, properties

Is it possible to edit the options of an object like `Plot` or `Graphics` after I store it as a variable?

For example, consider the following Voronoi mesh

```
VoronoiMesh[RandomReal[1, {5, 2}],
 ImageSize -> Medium,
 Epilog -> 
  Inset[Framed[Column[{BarLegend["Rainbow"]}, Alignment -> Center], 
    Background -> White], {Right, Bottom}, {Right, Bottom}]]
```

[image]

Now, if I set

```
mesh = VoronoiMesh[RandomReal[1, {5, 2}]];
```

My goal is to "edit" the object `mesh` and include the two options for `ImageSize` and `Epilog`

```
ImageSize -> Medium,
Epilog -> 
 Inset[Framed[Column[{BarLegend["Rainbow"]}, Alignment -> Center], 
   Background -> White], {Right, Bottom}, {Right, Bottom}]
```

I have tried something with `SetOptions` and `SetProperty`, but nothing seems to work. Something like

```
SetOptions[mesh,
 ImageSize -> Medium,
 Epilog -> 
  Inset[Framed[Column[{BarLegend["Rainbow"]}, Alignment -> Center], 
    Background -> White], {Right, Bottom}, {Right, Bottom}]]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the output of [`VoronoiMesh`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VoronoiMesh) is a [`MeshRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshRegion), use [`MeshRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshRegion) to change options. An example mesh:

```
SeedRandom[1]
mesh = VoronoiMesh[RandomReal[1, {5, 2}]]
```

[image]

Using [`MeshRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshRegion) to change options:

```
MeshRegion[mesh,
    ImageSize -> Medium,
    Epilog -> Inset[
        Framed[Column[{BarLegend["Rainbow"]},Alignment->Center],Background->White],
        {Right,Bottom},
        {Right,Bottom}
    ]
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is great. What about `Graphics` or `Plot`? Can something similar be used?